# Regex to extract number from a string in php

Tags: php, regex

I am new to php and I need help with a code that needs to extract the numbers from a string so that I can increment it then build the original string back.

The string that I want to  extract the number from looks like this:
hr-0001
I want to extract 0001
then increment it to 0002
and put it back together so it would look like
hr-0002

Comment: Can we see what your original non-working code looks like so we can give you proper guidance?

Comment: explode() on the hyphen is one way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't actually need to use a regex for this; [the `++` ("increment") operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) handles strings in exactly the way that you need.

```
$s = 'hr-0001';
++$s;
echo $s;   # prints 'hr-0002'
```

Comment: Pretty clever, but `hr-0009` will turn into `hr-0010` which may not be desired. +1 anyways since I have no clue what the OP is trying to accomplish, and this is a rather elegant solution.

Comment: @Madmartigan: Wait, what? What else could the desired behavior be? :-/

Comment: Might rather have `hr-00090` or `hr-00091`. I have no clue, these look like order numbers or something, at some point they will repeat using this method (`hr-9999` --> `hr-0000`). Just thought it would be important to note.

Comment: ah the noob that i am..thanks so much.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback("/\d+/", ...)`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) for that. In your custom callback function, just increment the string, and add some padding with [`str_pad`](http://php.net/str_pad) before returning it. The `preg_replace_callback` will do it in place.